# Does the clock that appears when you click the time appear in analog by default?

Tags: 20.04, clock, gnome-clocks

Does the clock that appears when you click the time at the top of the screen, appear in analog by default?

Because I thought it did, and now it stopped, but am I mistaken and it actually never did? And do I need Gnome Tweak Tools to add an analog clock?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the clock that appears when you click the time at the top of the
> screen, appear in analog by default?

No. The clock by default is digital but you can use TWEAKS to extend what is displayed such as the day of the week and the date.

However, I think you are you referring to the GNOME Extension Analogue Clock

[image]